# glass backlight does not appear in final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, glass

in the rendered viewport view I can see the emission panel behind the cube, but in the final render, it does not appear. What should be the problem? thank you
[image]

Comment: hello, it's not clear what you're talking about? have you checked the render visibility in the Outliner? maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sorry, the plane is there in the final render but the emission is not seen through the ice cube (glass material, 0 rough). The first pic is the rendered view and the left is the final render. Visibility is on in the outliner

Comment: could you please share your file? don't forget to pack all the images: pasteall.org/blend  once uploaded, copy paste the URL

Comment: Moonboots, here is the blend: https://pasteall.org/blend/d442988447b4413e9eeb983b1981f359

Answer (score 0):

I don't get some things in your files but it looks like you need to deactivate the *Show Emitter* option in the *Particles* panel if you want to have the exact same result. I hope it solves your problems.

[image]

Comment: Dear Moonboots, Thank you!! I deactivated the show emitter and it is getting better, (but still not the same as in the viewport) I appreciate your help!

Comment: there are still some things that I don't get but glad if it helped  ;)

Comment: I made some additional adjustments at viewport settings and now it's 100% the same! thank you again:)